# Will Nextflix Widevine L1 play with magisk?

Tags: netflix, amazon-video

If my phone natively supports Widevine L1 in order to play 1080p to 4K videos on Netflix or Amazon Prime, will Netflix play the high res rather than 480p with magisk that passes safetynet.

Comment: I can confirm the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlikely. Generally, on most phones, your DRM keys will be wiped when you unlock the bootloader. So, even if you clear SafetyNet, your Widevine level is most likely already dropped down to L3. That means no more HD playback. Locking the bootloaderback will work on some phones, won't on others. Ideally, it is a permanent loss of Widevine L1 when you unlock with no way to restore it.

I am not sure if there are some **hacks** which pass fake Widevine status to the apps in question and restore their HD playback.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to cancel my netflix subscription instead.

Comment: @singhnsk I disagree with you. Simply unlocking the bootloader doesn t means losing the L1. I tried to see if I could still play L1 videos on my Galaxy tab S3 after unlocking the bootloader but before rooting it and it worked.

Comment: @user2284570 can you kindly check with the DRM Info app about what's your current Widevine status? The drop in widevine should happen on every well secured Android device. In case it didn't on the Samsung, then it is Samsung which is not properly following the implementation of DRM.

Comment: @singhnsk I confirm it still shows that level. I suppose Samsung does it only once the efuse is trapped.